# Working with 2 Mouse instances in a Flash / AS3 game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

I have to code a 2-Player Flash / AS3 Video game. Each player must control a box, and with them, they have to catch elements that fall from the "sky". The user that after one minute has caught more of these elements wins.

The users are supposed to move their boxes with the mouse, but for it I'd need to listen mouse events from 2 different sources.

Could I get for each MouseEvent.CLICK, MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE and MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP from what source (mouse device - player) they came?

Thanks for your help!

Jordi

Comment: If you are not targeting touch screen systems with multiple input points I don't think it is possible to have 2 unique cursors / mice on a system. If you are though I would first look into flash.ui.Multitouch and related classes http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that one computer will have two mice plugged into it, and you want to use them from within Flash? Flash does not support this at all as most operating systems don't even support this feature. If you are talking about multiplayer over two computers, you will have to use network sockets to rely the realtime data.

As an alternative, you can make one type of input mouse and the other type keyboard for shared screen multiplay. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is what I suspected... Actually the game will be coded for a smartboard, which has support for two users doing multitouch simultaneously. The point is that it takes some of the touch events as Mouse Events, and due to I have to adapt some code I did before that gets mouse events, I considered this possibility. I'll try to ask the smartboard developers for an SDK or something similar, so as to get all this touch events from "outside".